# Show that Intersection and union of Ka is compact

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $ \{ K_a \} $ be a collection of compact subsets of a metric space $(X,d)$.

a) Show that $ \cap_{a=1}^\infty K_a$ is compact.

b) Give an example showing that $\cup_{a=1}^\infty K_a$ is not necessarily compact.

I found few solutions online but most of them are too complicated and lengthy for me to understand.

Comment: For the first one, the fact that you are taking an arbitrary intersection hints at using closed sets - When is a closed set compact, and when is a compact set closed?

Comment: @Carl I just realized.

Comment: What about the second part?

Comment: Single point sets are always compact, and every set is a union of points